# Organizar tabela de horários no Banco de Dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Para a construção de uma tabela no site que conterá uma listagem de todos os dias da semana, como posso criar essas tabelas no banco de dados? Por exemplo:

Horarios da linha de onibus de uma cidade para outra:

De CidadeA para cidadeB

Seg à Sex

7:00h
7:30h
10:00h
  ...

Sab

7:15h
11:30h

Dom

12:00h

...

CidadeB à CidadeC

.....

Como organizo os dias da semana e horarios no banco? para que o próprio admin do sistema possa alterar essas informações constantemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode organizar da seguinte forma:

```
id_horario // auto increment
id_linha // linha pré cadastrada
id_saida // cidade saida
id_destino // cidade destino
dia_da_semana // segunda a domingo 
horario // horário de saida
```

Com base nessa tablela, você faz a inserção dos registros de horários e linhas dos ônibus. Quando você for gravar, verifica se já tem esse horário agendado nessa linha, se não tem, grava, se tem edita.

Espero ter ajudado!